# Binding a Function to jPlayer's "next" Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, jplayer

jPlayer's jPlayerPlaylist addon documentation is not very complete so I'm hoping someone on here has a solution for this problem. I need a function to fire whenever the next command is triggered.

For example, this code should cause a binded function to fire:

```
playlist.next();
```

Where "playlist" is an object containing jPlayer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
playlist.bind($.jPlayer.event.next, function() { alert("next"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind a listener on the button using a jQuery selector. You won't be able to stop the next track from starting though.

One more tip: the start event is fired when using the next button. You just need to detect the difference with the first start and a stop/start.

Comment: Thanks, but the next command is triggered in many more situations than just when you click the next button, such as when a song ends and the next is loaded.